PrimeNG p-calendar component with minDate issue when using formcontrol
I have upgraded my project from v15 to Angular v18/PrimeNG v17 and in my component:
                      <p-calendar
                        dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
                        formControlName="finish_date"
                        [minDate]="today"
                      >
                      </p-calendar>

when I have date saved in DB and it is today or in the past, the field stays empty.
I want to minDate only for new inputs, but the field should display dates even in the past if already saved.

it is related to primeng V18 upgrade
you can add the :
[keepInvalid]="true" 

attribute to the p-calendar component. This will help manage the minDate issue when using formControlName.
<p-calendar
      dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"
      formControlName="finish_date"
      [minDate]="today"
      [keepInvalid]="true">
</p-calendar>

it will fix the issue

Amazing! Thanks a lot. I had some onShow/onClose terrible solution, but finally it looks "clean".
